# Allowing a wget to run as part of a command line parameter

Tags: bash

I'm writing a little script that takes several command line arguments and substitutes their values into some files.
I have a requirement where the user can either specify a file on their machine, or fetch it over http(s), but the problem is my script eats up the wget as a parameter, and doesn't actually execute it.

Here's what I'm using to parse the arguments:

```
while [[ "$#" -gt 0 ]] ; do   
    if [[ "$1" == '--ip-address' ]] ; then  
        shift  
        ip_address="$1"  
    fi  
    if [[ "$1" == '--hostname' ]] ; then  
        shift  
        hostname="$1"  
    fi
    shift
done
```

What I'm looking for is something like
`script.sh --file wget http://foo.bar/file.txt` and it would first download the file and then pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Why do not refactor your script and command line on this way: `script.sh --file http://foo.bar/file.txt` and check for `://` string and if present use `wget`

Comment: `script.sh --file <(curl http://foo.bar/file.txt)` ? (or `wget -O /dev/stdout `)

Comment: Given the requirement, it sounds like you're supposed to accept  `--url http://foo.bar/file.txt` or `--file file.txt` (or autodetect) , and in the former case use `wget` yourself. You are not supposed to write `wget` when you run the program.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
 if [[ "$1" == '--file' ]] ; then  
        shift  
        filename="$1"
        if [ `echo $filename|grep '://'` != "" ]; then
           wget --no-check-certificate -O /tmp/file "$filename"
           filename=/tmp/file
        fi
    fi
```